# Vue3 stubbed component trigger event with params and get return value

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, stub

I'm testing my component with jest.
Inside it I have a custom component I stub:

```
function mountComponent(propsData, data) {
    const wrapper = mount(Upload, {
        props: propsData,
        global: {
            stubs: {
                myCustomComponent: true,
            },
            plugins: [router],
        },
        data,
    });

    return wrapper;
}
```

my usage of the custom componenet is:

```
<my-custom-component
    @upload="uploadMethod"
></my-custom-component>
```

I saw I can trigger the method uploadMethod by:

```
    const upload = wrapper.find('component-stub');
    upload.trigger('uploadMethod');
```

but my method - uploadmethod has both parameters and return value
my question is how can I set the parameters and how can I get the return value?

Comment: `upload.trigger('uploadMethod', ...args)`. Note `trigger` does not return a promise, so the `await` is redundant. If you need more help you have to show us what the `upload()` method in the component you're testing is expecting.

Comment: the args part from what I saw adds the arguments I'm adding to the event object the method receives.
but my method looks something like that:
function uploadMethod(intParamA, intParamB) : number {...}

Comment: Rather than providing details in comments, update the question itself when you are asked for them. It is important that the question is understood without reading the comments. By clarifying the question, you make it more useful. A more useful question has a bigger chance of drawing useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *my question is how can I set the parameters...*

Exactly like calling `uploadMethod(...args)` directly, except you add the event name as first parameter:

```
const args = [param1, param2, param3];
const upload = wrapper.find('component-stub');
upload.trigger('uploadMethod', ...args);
```

> *... and how can I get the return value?*

You don't, because the subcomponent doesn't, either. You `expect()` that whatever should have happened in the parent component when `uploadMethod` is called ***actually** happened*.